# Simulation shows mystery leakage

Tags: transistors, simulation, npn, leakage-current

**Background:**

I am trying to design a battery powered gate opener, the basic concept is that if the uC switch is on the relay switches the motor on, but if the actuator gives a low feedback (gate is fully open) I want the motor to stop i.e. it overrides the other switch. This all works however when both switched are open it should not draw power however it actually draws 11.772mA which I just can't work out how.
In the diagram below Pink is power Blue is current.
The complication with this is that as well as switch of the actuator when gate is open I also want to signal to uC that it is open so the uC will have a pull up resistor in place and listen for when it is pulled low. That is represented by V3 and R6.

**I don't understand how 11.772mA goes from V2 through R4 then the relay and Q1(BC547B) NPN to ground??**

**And how is the base of Q1 715mV??**

If it helps the simulation says NPN Q1 is also HOT??

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The cathode in the optoisolator should be 3.3V if the current path is really open, so I suspect some leakage there. What is the optoisolator output dark current specified at?

Comment: It's due to reverse D2 current leakage.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Looks like you are right the Diode has IS of 40u is that really enough to make that much of a differance?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič yes you are correct I selected an incorrect Diode it should have been IN4148 which has an IS of 2nA not 40u from what I can see 40u is unusually high. with the currect one selected it now leaks in the u range. If you and as an answer I will select it,

Comment: Nice simulation results representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to reverse D2 current leakage.